# How to on the fly replace an image from the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

How to on the fly replace this picture? (without removing the html SVG element and re-rendering it)

`xlink:href="http://missosology.info/forum/download/file.php?avatar=11666_1307312313.jpg"`

**CODE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bfv17f0e/

```
<svg class="clip-svg user-img" width="36" height="36" viewBox="0 0 560 645">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="polygon-clip">                        
      <polygon points="270,0 0,160 0,485 270,445 560,0 0,160"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <image clip-path="url(#polygon-clip)" 
         height="100%" 
         width="100%" 
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         xlink:href="http://missosology.info/forum/download/file.php?avatar=11666_1307312313.jpg"
         >   
  </image>

</svg>
```

**EDIT:**

```
$('image').attr('xlink:href', 'new image'); its not working not replacing the image, how do i replace that url?
```

Comment: Same as you would replace any other DOM element.

Comment: @dfsq is it possible to stop _re-rendering_? doesn't make sense to me in this question.

Comment: You can avoid removing and replacing the SVG element. But avoiding re-rendering would...kinda obviate the point of updating the image, surely.

Comment: @YumYumYum: Can you put a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) in the question? So we can see the problem and to make it easier to help you?

Comment: Tested: `$('image').attr('xlink:href', newPath)`. Works fine.  Create a demo, or it's hard to help.

Comment: Your selector needs to be more specific, yes. But it's not the issue. `$('image').attr('xlink:href', newPath)` would work anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works.

`$('image').attr('xlink:href', newPath)`